# How to insert mulitple record with pl/sql block?I am getting erro msg in this code

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
procedure Emat(i in number) is
begin
Execute immediate 'insert all
  into Piping(Ename,Eid,location,technology,salary)
  values('||sharjil||',||333||,'||new delhi||','||Emat||',||19000||)'

  into Piping(Ename,Eid,location,technology,salary) values('||amol||',||222||,'||noida||','||vlsi||',22222)
  select * from dual;

  dbms_output.put_line('You are in Emat procedure');
end;

begin
  Emat(1);
end;
```

Comment: Should we guess the error?  Or do you want to tell us?  Why are you using dynamic SQL in the first place?  What is your code intended to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a string when you use 'Execute immediate' command.

Execute immediate ' << your code >> ';

Any question just let me know.

Thanks.